# How add node as an update in postgres table column

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin

Here is what is the `JSON` value in my table

```
  {
 "quiz":{
  "sport":{
     "q1":{
        "question":"Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
        "options":[
           "New York Bulls",
           "Los Angeles Kings",
           "Golden State Warriros",
           "Huston Rocket"
        ],
        "answer":"Huston Rocket"
     }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add `"hint":" HR"` at the label of `options` i saw something like

```
UPDATE test SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{answer}', '"New York Bulls"');
```

but this is to update existing key but i want to have to add it.